# Problem with php version (7.4) and error 500 if php 7.3 on PrestaShop 17.7.2

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have a problem with a store.

She uses ShippingBo to manage her orders except that lately, it doesn't work anymore.

Here is the error that returned:

```
<error>
  <code>
    <![CDATA[ 15 ]]>
  </code><message>
    <![CDATA[ [PHP Unknown error #8192] array_key_exists(): Using array_key_exists() on objects is deprecated. Use isset() or property_exists() instead (/home/pzkb4321/public_html/src/Adapter/EntityMapper.php, line 99) ]]>
  </message>
</error>
```

After some research, I know that it is probably due to the version of PHP and indeed, my server is not on the right version.

It uses PHP 7.4 and for Prestashop 1.7 you need PHP 7.3.

I tried to change the PHP version of my server except that I ended up with a 500 error on my site.

[PrestaShopDatabaseException]

Unknown MySQL error

```
SELECT s.id_shop, CONCAT(su.physical_uri, su.virtual_uri) AS uri, su.domain, su.main FROM by_shop_url su LEFT JOIN by_shop s ON (s.id_shop = su.id_shop) WHERE (su.domain = 'belym.com' OR su.domain_ssl = 'belym.com') AND s.active = 1 AND s.deleted = 0 ORDER BY LENGTH(CONCAT(su.physical_uri, su.virtual_uri)) DESC
```

at line 769 in file classes/db/Db.php

```
if ($webservice_call && $errno) {
    $dbg = debug_backtrace();
    WebserviceRequest::getInstance()->setError(500, '[SQL Error] ' . $this->getMsgError() . '. From ' . (isset($dbg[3]['class']) ? $dbg[3]['class'] : '') . '->' . $dbg[3]['function'] . '() Query was : ' . $sql, 97);
} elseif (_PS_DEBUG_SQL_ && $errno && !defined('PS_INSTALLATION_IN_PROGRESS')) {
    if ($sql) {
        throw new PrestaShopDatabaseException($this->getMsgError() . '<br /><br /><pre>' . $sql . '</pre>');
    }
 
    throw new PrestaShopDatabaseException($this->getMsgError());
    }
}
```

[image: error screen]

Thank you for your help